# How to convert RTF to PDF in Grails?

Tags: grails, pdf-generation

we are programming in Grails and as part our system requirement we need to have the option to convert a RTF document to PDF. We found a service in OpenOffice that does the job, but would like to have something that doesn't depend on other application's services. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grails is based on Groovy which is based on Java, so use any Java PDF libraries from with in your Grails app. I'm not sure if any of these will help, or how your generating the RTF files but take a look at the following link for a list of Java PDF libraries and components.http://java-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries